# determine if udp socket can be accessed via external client

Tags: server, sockets

I don't have access to company firewall server. but supposedly the port 1720 is open on my one  ubuntu server. So I want to test it with netcat:

```
sudo nc -ul 1720
```

The port is listening on the machine ITSELF:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep nc
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1720            0.0.0.0:*                           29477/nc
```

The port is open and in use on the machine ITSELF:

```
lsof -i -n -P | grep 1720
gateway 980 myuser    8u  IPv4 187284576      0t0  UDP *:1720
```

Checked the firewall on current server:

```
sudo ufw allow 1720/udp
Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)
sudo ufw status verbose | grep 1720
1720/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
1720/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

But I try echoing data to it from another computer (I replaced the x's with the real integers):

```
echo "Some data to send" | nc xx.xxx.xx.xxx 1720
```

But it didn't write anything. So then I try with telnet from the other computer as well:

```
telnet xx.xxx.xx.xxx 1720
Trying xx.xxx.xx.xxx...
telnet: connect to address xx.xxx.xx.xxx: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Although I don't think telnet works with udp sockets.

I ran nmap from another computer within the same local network and this is what I got:

```
sudo nmap -v -A -sU -p 1720 xx.xxx.xx.xx

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-10-31 15:41 EDT
NSE: Loaded 36 scripts for scanning.
Initiating Ping Scan at 15:41
Scanning xx.xxx.xx.xx [4 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 15:41, 0.10s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 15:41
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 15:41, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating UDP Scan at 15:41
Scanning xtremek.com (xx.xxx.xx.xx) [1 port]
Completed UDP Scan at 15:41, 0.07s elapsed (1 total ports)
Initiating Service scan at 15:41
Initiating OS detection (try #1) against xtremek.com (xx.xxx.xx.xx)
Retrying OS detection (try #2) against xtremek.com (xx.xxx.xx.xx)
Initiating Traceroute at 15:41
Completed Traceroute at 15:41, 0.01s elapsed
NSE: Script scanning xx.xxx.xx.xx.
NSE: Script Scanning completed.
Nmap scan report for xtremek.com (xx.xxx.xx.xx)
Host is up (0.00013s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE VERSION
1720/udp closed unknown
Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details
Network Distance: 1 hop

TRACEROUTE (using port 1720/udp)
HOP RTT     ADDRESS
1   0.13 ms xtremek.com (xx.xxx.xx.xx)

Read data files from: /usr/share/nmap
OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.04 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 27 (2128B) | Rcvd: 24 (2248B).
```

The only thing I can think of is a firewall or vpn issue. Is there anything else I can check for before requesting that they look at the firewall server again?

Comment: You need to make sure that Gateways/Firewalls handle the port correctly.

Comment: I don't have access to firewall @Braiam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several tools can be used to check for open ports or scan your computer. In general, because connections from localhost (your computer) will automatically be accepted, you should scan from a second computer on your LAN. nmap is one of several options.

```
nmap -v -A ip_address
```

Or if the server is pesky about pings ...

```
nmap -v -A -PN ip_address
```

nmap has additional capabilities as well =).

Additional tools you can use on your computer (rather then scanning from a remote location):

```
netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep -v ^unix

netstat -ntulp

lsof -i -n -P
```

Comment: UPDATE: I ran the following command: "nmap -v -A -p 1720 xx.xxx.xx.xxx". This is what it told me: PORT     STATE  SERVICE     VERSION
1720/tcp closed H.323/Q.931

Comment: you said it's closed. but how come "sudo netstat -tulpn | grep nc" shows this: udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1720            0.0.0.0:*                           29477/nc   . When I run that on the server itself, it shows that it is listening. However, when I ran nmap command on the other server in network, it said udp was closed. So what actually is the problem? A firewall?

Comment: lsof doesn't show anything is using the port. But for sure I have a netcat server listening on it

Comment: did you run lsof as root? sudo lsof ....

Comment: Sorry lsof shows this: gateway 980 guarddoguser    8u  IPv4 187284576      0t0  UDP *:1720

Comment: nmap isn't reliable. I tested it with another port on that other server and it showed it was closed even though I know for sure that one is open.

Comment: guarddog is a graphical tool to manage your firewall. I am not sure what it is doing with port 1720. At any rate , turn your firewall off. nmap is a reliable tool, lol

Comment: guarddoguser is just a placeholder for the current user im logged in as. I know the program running on 1720. At first I was using netcat. But now I have a real socket server running on it I created with c++. However, neither netcat or my socket server are detecting udp packets coming into that port 1720, hence my question. Don't have access to firewall server, but I will try to get it off in order to see if that is issue

Comment: lol, are you running a firewall in the local machine ? ufw? iptables? output of `iptables -l`

Comment: No it's another firewall server running fedora on a seperate machine. Traffic goes through that firewall server before it hits my local machine. So it can block access to certain ports on my server. Plus there is a vpn.

Comment: Well, that is the problem, ports will be closed if they are firewalled. You should be able to access services locally, http://localhost for example.

Answer (score 0):

How are you?

Do you try with netstat?

There is a lot of way to see if your port is open, may be this can help you:

**sudo netstat -lp --inet**

Its important sudo mode. This will list all your open port, and must appear. Another way to do same is:

**sudo netstat -plut**

Try it, and tell me.

Take Care.